# vega charts with simple data format

Tags: vega

I am trying to plot and display a stacked area chart from an array of values where each array element contains the x value and index, the y value and the y2 value.

All the examples work with a more complex data structure requiring transformation and I'm a little lost, can anyone provide and example or syntax for renderrng this simple array in vega as a stacked area chart using vega.js?

```
 var yourVlSpec = {
            "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
            "title": "Assets At Risk",
            "width": 500,
            "height": 200,
            "padding": 5,

            "data": {
                "values": [{
                    "y_val": 190250,
                    "x_val": 0,
                    "y1_val": 190250
                }, {
                    "y_val": 187750,
                    "x_val": 2,
                    "y1_val": 190250
                }, {
                    "y_val": 185250,
                    "x_val": 3,
                    "y1_val": 190250
                }, {
                    "y_val": 182750,
                    "x_val": 4,
                    "y1_val": 190250
                }, {
                    "y_val": 180250,
                    "x_val": 5,
                    "y1_val": 190250
                }]
            },
            "mark": {
                "type": "area"
            },
            "encoding": {
                "x": {
                    "field": "x_val",
                    "title": "Year",
                    "type": "quantitative"
                },
                "y": {
                    "field": "y_val",
                     "title": "y"
                },
                "y2": {
                    "field": "y1_val",
                    "title": "y1"

                },
            },
        }

        vegaEmbed('#vis', yourVlSpec);
```

Comment: Your data makes no sense to me. What is "protected". Is "x_val" really 58 or should it be 5? What is the y1_val supposed to represent? If it is a range, why does the first entry go from 190250 to 190250? You have trailing commas everywhere too. How will the different stacks be differentiated i.e. what field provides the colour key? I think you need to provide a diagram of what you expect and then we can see if your data is sufficient.

Comment: I have removed trailing commas and any typos.

It should be a stacked area chart, in this instance yhe y1_val for all elements is 190250,, but it will not always be, but in this instance it woudld be a flat line.

Can the color key for y1 and y2 be provided in an other area of the spec?

The dat contains the values for, x, y, y2  [x_val, y_val, y1_val] nothing else, does the dat need to be transformed?

Or is there a simpler way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Vega is not the same as Vega-Lite. Your example code is in Vega-Lite so here's a solution in Vega-Lite.

For [area chart](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/area.html), Vega-Lite expects the data to have a field that defines the line for each of the area in the area chart. In the Vega-Lite [example stacked area chart](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/stacked_area.html), that field is ["series"](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/data/unemployment-across-industries.json).

In the solution shown here, your data is restructured to have a field "series" similar to the Vega-Lite example, and y values are changed to show the areas more clearly.

[View in Vega-Lite on-line editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAdxoATemgDMABh1L4NMljQAmPUrVJMKVKGJJBDOBDQBtUBDgAnGi7QgAIKKIAAeAPoOgmj6IACekY5mOqZiOgC+Cp4+fq7oAEIhEVExSgklqACMKWmZ2b7+6MFKxUmopmWJ0VUA7D21WSBeDXkghS1dZp0V5qkZg8O5Ac1hk6ha021ic3VDOY1jRWsb8WuzA-VLTUcVACyb3ZWm-fOXB+Ordw9o1TsL+6MVq1umJvlUaq89iMAh9gWhQacKr9agBdTIgZDeADWaFAmDiODgASQ3jgKHRcFkUDYahosjIuLCjIAZn5BGoAnClPjCQEAI4MJCyTB0aw0UghJChGh5UCCJBMOCCQL0wRE1AZdFxFlsjnocpJJRIMhkUkUTDqoYMBAgdHUwRsbw6pV6qFLJTQRzqzywRCWqDWciOuLVW3pcNAA)
[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "width": 300, "height": 200,
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"series": "A", "x_val": 0, "y_val": 20250},
      {"series": "B", "x_val": 0, "y_val": 10250},
      {"series": "A", "x_val": 2, "y_val": 17750},
      {"series": "B", "x_val": 2, "y_val": 20250},
      {"series": "A", "x_val": 3, "y_val": 5250},
      {"series": "B", "x_val": 3, "y_val": 20250},
      {"series": "A", "x_val": 4, "y_val": 12750},
      {"series": "B", "x_val": 4, "y_val": 10250},
      {"series": "A", "x_val": 5, "y_val": 10250},
      {"series": "B", "x_val": 5, "y_val": 10250}
    ]
  },
  "mark": {
    "type": "area"
    },
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "x_val",
      "type": "quantitative", 
      "axis": {"labelAngle": 0}
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "y_val",
      "aggregate": "sum",
    },
    "color": {
      "field": "series",
      "scale": {"scheme": "category10"}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if I don't want to aggregate but just plot the values directly how would I do that?

Comment: e.g. not stacked

Comment: To plot lines (not area), just change the mark type from "area" to "line" in Answer 1. For "Ranged Area" chart, see Answer 2.

Answer (score 1):

Vega-Lite [Area chart](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/area.html) documentaion does not show plotting arbitrary lines as areas because the overalpping areas would be dfficult to interpret.

For data with 2 lines and one set of values always higher than the other, take a look at the ["Ranged Area"](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/area.html#ranged) chart example.

Here is a Ranged Area chart using your example data. Note use of your original data structure.

[View in Vega-Lite on-line editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAdxoATemgDMABh1L4NMljQAmPUrVJMKVKGJJBDOBDQBtUAE8A+g8FoARgBOHVMxfRAAD19HNAjPAJj-VGDQ8IBfBS8kwIAOAHZ88KVovzMlBJyUkLCdTOyylNyxWpKqrQrExtTa+pAfbtzTIojS2NQAFk6qnoys-pnctNGqsWnumoyAXUyQZAAnAGs0UExPHDg0ECR9uBQlNhwkKDpPOMoOkGFZS9RMfecShwbBoskwaH+zl2cFkUDYalBZBOUWRADMaHBBGormN-EozhcrgBHBhIMF0aw0UiKa6RGiuOxfJBMTEAQVkZEEvzquzejKQZDItwomF+eyQkRp6Mx2PQA1ivNMyIFQr4oquCFBUoxWKulTK6UNQA)

[image]

```
 {
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "width": 300,
  "height": 200,
   "data": {
                "values": [{
                    "y_val": 190250,
                    "x_val": 0,
                    "y1_val": 190250
                }, {
                    "y_val": 187750,
                    "x_val": 2,
                    "y1_val": 190250
                }, {
                    "y_val": 185250,
                    "x_val": 3,
                    "y1_val": 190250
                }, {
                    "y_val": 182750,
                    "x_val": 4,
                    "y1_val": 190250
                }, {
                    "y_val": 180250,
                    "x_val": 5,
                    "y1_val": 190250
                }]
            },
  "mark": {"type": "area",
          "opacity": 0.3,
          "line": true, 
          "point": true
  },
  "encoding": {
   "x": {"field": "x_val", 
          "type": "quantitative", 
          "axis": {"labelAngle": 0}
    },
    "y": {
      "aggregate": "max",
      "field": "y_val"
    },
    "y2": {"aggregate": "min", 
      "field": "y1_val"
    }

  }
}
```